# How do I make my user level application communicate to a root level application through pipes?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

I have a user level application that needs to enable/disable a device by writing to it's device file(which requires root privileges).

Here's the current implementation of my interface:

```
bool DeviceInterface::EnableDevice( bool isEnabled )
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;

    //enable device
    if(isEnabled)
    {
        isSuccessful = (system("enableDevice.sh 1") == 0)? true : false;
    }
    //disable device
    else
    {
        isSuccessful = (system("enableDevice.sh 0") == 0)? true : false;
    }
    return isSuccessful ;
}
```

My script "enableDevice.sh" simply looks like this, and runs just fine when ran as root:

```
echo $1 > /sys/devices/device_file
```

This fails as it requires root privileges to be able to write to a device file. I'm totally new to "pipes", "fork" and "exec". Can anybody help me  how I could pass "0" or "1" to a script to enable and disable the device?

Comment: Do you have admin rights? Or must any user be able to _enable_ / _disable_ the device?

Comment: user application has no admin rights. but the script does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for 'enableDevice.sh' to do this, it needs to be running as root.  You could mark it suid
(chmod u+S enableDevice.sh) and chown it to root.  Note that you'll need to be root to do the chown (on any reasonable unix system).

Of course you could always open up write permissions for your (well, the programs') group or for everyone, i.e.
    chmod g+w,o+w /sys/devices/device_file

I *REALLY* wouldn't recommend you do this.  if I called that script with '\"bunch of nothing at all > /dev/sda' it'd overwrite the (likely) root of your system drive.

A better idea would be to have the script check what "$1" is, and then echo 0 or 1 to the device, or do nothing if it's neither.  i.e. don't trust user data, especially in suid scripts!

```
case "$1" in
    enable)   VALUE=1 ;;
    disable)  VALUE=0 ;;
    *)        exit  ;;
esac
echo $VALUE > /sys/devices/device_file
```

Better still, have a deamon which you've run as root hanging around watching a named pipe which does (effectively) the above, depending on what it gets in the pipe.

Comment: setuid shell scripts don't work. opening up the permissions, or the daemon are reasonable alternatives, though

Comment: what is the numeric value of chmod +S?

Comment: 4000, i.e. 4 in the first digit place, but note the comments hereabouts on suid scripts

Answer (score 1):

Run chmod on enableDevice.sh as follows ( being root) :-

```
   #chmod 4755 enableDevice.sh
```

It's called setting the setuid bit.  With this non-root users will be able to run this script and it will run with the owner's ( who in our case : root) privileges.
And thus your program will work.
Do read about setuid.
EDIT : Also, before chmod, make the owner and group of enableDevice.sh as root. Then only it will work.

Comment: setuid shell scripts generally don't work - see http://serverfault.com/questions/93883/ubuntu-setuid-bash-doesnt-work it's got to do with the way the script is invoked

Comment: I tested with a single line script ( like the one OP has ) hello.sh having just "echo Hello World" in it and it is working as expected.

Comment: Yes Petesh, you are right. It didn't work when I changed the line to  "echo hello >> /root/a" where /root/a is a simple text file created by root. Thanks for the info.

Comment: what is the numeric value of chmod +S?